# ESLint demands semicolon and wants it removed at the same time

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am configuring ESLint (as TSLint is soon-to-be-deprecated) to work with my .ts files. I have this very little file:

```
export default interface Departure {
  line: string;
  direction: string;
  time: Date;
};
```

in the last time, where semicolon is, ESLint in my VSCode signals two errors: one about missing semicolon `eslint(semi)` and another one about unnecessary semicolon `eslint(no-extra-semi)`.

[image: eslint semicolon error]

Below is my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
            }
        }
    },
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

how can I get rid of this bizarre situation? None of the errors should be there.

Answer (score 50):

The issue here is that 2 rules are applied at the same time:

1. `export default` requires to have a semicolon
2. `interface` requires to get rid of a semicolon

The fix here would be to split the declaration of the interface from the export statement like so:

```typescript
interface Departure {
  line: string;
  direction: string;
  time: Date;
}

export default Departure;
```

I didn't come up with the answer myself. Source was this [submitted issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/123)

Comment: This is a workaround for the specific situation but it does not resolve the underlying issue. "semi" and "@typescript-eslint/semi" do the same thing expect @typescript-eslint/semi is built for typescript. Running both risks creating the situation described in this question in another form.

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this question using the followed rules:

```
"rules": {
  "semi": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error"],
}
```

Comment: This turns off errors for missing semicolons everywhere, which is not nice.

Comment: @Marko Bjelac Try"@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error", "always"]. Otherwise it won't check every line just syntaxicly ambiguous ones. This is the exact setup I use with typescript and it does report missing simi-colons. @typescript-eslint/semi supersedes "semi" in for TypeScript code.

Comment: @ricardo-emerson, would you mind explaining the reasoning behind your suggestion, please?

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Ricardo Emerson's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61945947/7677851), the following `.eslintrc` setup will  **not** turn off the semicolon errors:

```
{
  ...
  "extends": [
    ...
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    ...
    "semi": ["error", "never"],
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": "off",
    "no-unexpected-multiline": "error"
  }
}
```

According to the documentation, it is also recommended to turn on the `no-unexpected-multiline` errors when turning off semicolons.

Comment: rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
    'semi': 0,
  },

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Pulling together several answers here we the workaround of splitting the export and interface definition to separate lines. That will resolve the specific error but does not prevent it from happening again.

From  Ricardo Emerson's answer the fallowing eslint config lines will allow semi-colon checking to be left on while resolving the conflict:

```
"rules": {
  "semi": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error"],
}
```

Or if that seems to shut off checking compeltely try:

```
"rules": {
  "semi": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error", "always"],
}
```

"always" check is the default for "@typescript-eslint/semi" when its on but this setting may have been change in another configuration file.

To disable the check completely do:

```
"rules": {
  "semi": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/semi": "off",
}
```

This will deactivate both rules. Never turn both on "@typescript-eslint/semi" supersedes "semi". The docs specifically warn about this. See https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/semi.md

Comment: I'd like to additionally point out that TypeScript ESLint also warns not to use the @typescript-eslint/semi rule here: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/semi/.

Comment: Indead it does. Thanks for the doc link. The github link is the dev-side version which where in found it first There are other rules like this were modified for typescript syntax. Hence the name of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer here, is to disable semi and turn on @typescript-eslint/semi for eslint.

```
"rules": {
    ...,
    "semi": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/semi": ["error", "always"],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your .prettierrc file and remove/delete the  "semi": "off" rule, this way, when you save your working file, the semicolons required by your eslint would not be deleted.